# What is the best way to manage javascript resources for Visualforce pages?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, static-resources, tools

So at the moment when I want to make a quick tweak in a javascript file that enhances a Visualforce page, I have to go:

1. Setup >> Development >> Static Resources
2. Find my script in the list
   (takes a few clicks and page refreshes if it is low down on the
   list)
3. Click Delete I get a list of places where the resource is used
4. Open the pages mentioned in the code editor
5. Comment out the places
   where the script is used
6. Find the resource in the list again and try
   delete (almost there, don't give up now)
7. Now add that missing angle bracket in my desktop editor
8. Upload the file giving it the same name as before
9. Hop over in to the
   online code editor and remove the comments around all the places
   where the script is included and save.

Anyone know of a shorter routine?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just reupload the zip file again, no need to delete & reinsert. Simply click "Edit" and use the file upload field :)

And during development I tend to work on raw JS files (not zipped), I can then edit code directly in Eclipse IDE for example. I package up zips only when I'm ready to promote it to testing / production. You could reference both the "basic" static resource and later temporary static res with just this one troublesome JS file, if it contains function definitions they'll be overwritten.

Comment: Oh my, how did I miss that? I guess I expected a full code editor when I first clicked on Edit and then it looked like I could only edit the resource name. Thanks for saving me hours!

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if this would be a frowned upon approach or not, but in my frustration with what you have described above (whilst in development only) I created a Component to allow dynamic editing of Javascript

```
<apex:component controller="MappingController">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var greeting = "hello";
  </script>
</apex:component>
```

Think I had the controller in there because I was doing some remoting.

**EDIT**: Added VF Page source

```
<apex:page standardController="Project__c" extensions="MappingController" standardStylesheets="false">
  <c:Styles /> <!-- dynamic stylesheet editing here -->
  <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery3, 'css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css')}"/>
  <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery3, 'js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js')}"/>
  <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery3, 'js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js')}"/>
  <apex:sectionHeader title="Edit" subtitle="Mapping" />
    <apex:form >
      <div>some html or other</div>
    </apex:form>
    <c:MappingCanvas />        <!-- dynamic javascript editing here -->
    <c:Scripts />        
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hey Phil great idea. So you store all javascript stuff in just one component and load it just after apex:page notation?

Comment: @mast0r - basically yes, though looking at my source I have it at the bottom (not sure if there is a reason for that) - i'll edit my answer to show you.

Comment: Putting JavaScript at the bottom is a common optimization technique; it sometimes will allow browsers to render pages quicker.

Comment: @MikeChale, it may be a common optimization technique, but that isn't why I put it there, I think it was probably more to do with making my source easily visible from the clutter at the top when debugging. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Good tip, Phil!

Answer (score 2):

FWIW - It's also possible to update Static Resources via the Migration Tool.  In theory you could have your JavaScript as part of source control and loaded automatically into your org as part of a CI loop.

Answer (score 1):

Why so complicated? I'v created a static resource and uploaded all my JavaScripts as one zip-file (without .zip ending). Every tyme i want to update my script i just swapping out thet zip-file. Thats all.